# Java 6 Update - Mac OS X application crash related to QuickTime libraries

Tags: java, macos, quicktime

I currently am looking at a bug related to an **application crash** when running on Mac OS X. **The crash only seems to occur when using Java 6, with the Mac OS X 10.5 Update 1 (64 bit mode). The problem does not show up on 32bit Mac Java installs.**

From what I have read via google, the issue seems to be related to the fact that the application is making use of **QuickTime libraries,** which seem to be having problems with Java 6 running in **64 bit mode**.

> QuickTime for Java is based on 32-bit
>   Carbon libraries, and has been
>   effectively in “maintenance mode” for
>   a while. Unfortunately someone manages
>   to get the JNI (or JNA?) code working
>   it’s going to be difficult to work
>   around the problem using QTKit.

**Related references:**

- http://www.newtonslore.com/category/things-from-the-big-fruit/mac/java-on-mac-os-x/
- http://lists.apple.com/archives/quicktime-api/2009/Jun/msg00051.html
- [What are my options for running Java 6 on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331777/what-are-my-options-for-running-java-6-on-os-x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The JavaApplicationStub file in the
>   app bundle was configured to run
>   x86_64 which the library does not
>   support. This is apparently new to the
>   latest release of Java.
>
> In order to solve the problem, use the
>   lipo tool. Here is what I did:
>
> lipo -remove x86_64
>   JavaApplicationStub -output
>   JavaApplicationStub
>
> In addition it is also recommended
>   that the LSArchitecturePriority key be
>   added to the info.plist. I added the
>   following to the main properties:
>
> LSArchitecturePriority
>    i386
>   ppc
>
> This specifies the allowed
>   architectures in their preferred
>   order.

http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=9706490

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that native 32-bit libraries cannot be loaded by Mac Java 6 at all.  On the other hand, since Java 5 is still the default on Mac OS X, I am still using Java 5 for those applications requiring native libraries, since that is what my Mac customers use.

I realize that this is not, perhaps, a very helpful answer, but unless someone can enlighten us on how to use 32-bit native libraries with Java 6, this negative answer is the best I can do.

Comment: Yep, the Apple's Java 6 implementation for the Mac does not support 32-bit native code.